# If number of homomorphisms from $G \mapsto H$ is $n$. How many homomorphisms are there from $G \oplus G\cdot\cdot \cdot \oplus~ G ( s $ times) to $H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that the number of homomorphisms from $G \mapsto H$ is $n$. If $H$ is abelian, How many homomorphisms are there from $G \oplus G\cdot\cdot \cdot \oplus~ G ( s $ times) to $H$

**Attempt** Number of homomorphisms $\Psi: G \mapsto H$ is $n$ and we need the number of homomorphisms $G \oplus G\cdot\cdot \cdot \oplus~ G ( s $ times) to $H$

I have very little idea how to proceed further.

Help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Why and for which $Ψ$ do you have $|G/\operatorname{ker} Ψ| = n$?

Comment: $n^s$ is the correct answer, but your explanation makes no sense.

Comment: Number of homomorphisms from $G \mapsto H$ is $n$. Since, $G/Ker~\Psi \approx \Psi(G)$, then each distinct coset has $n$ options in $H$

Comment: Again: that makes no sense. In the first sentence of your comment there is no $\Psi$ while in the second one there is one.

Comment: @ZhenLin Isn't the explanation in my comment correct?

Comment: I just realized it was complete balderdash. Can someone please give me a hint on how to move further?

I am confused.

Comment: Are your groups abelian?

Comment: Yes, $H$ is abelian. Edited main post

Comment: I would say this is more or less the definition of $s$-fold direct sum. $\operatorname{Hom}(G,H)^s = \operatorname{Hom}(\bigoplus_s G, H)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a system of groups $G_1,…, G_s$ (in your situation, all of them are $G$).

For each summand $G_i$ in your direct sum, you have an inclusion morphism
$$\mathrm{incl}_i \colon G_i → G_1 \oplus G_2 \oplus … \oplus G_s,\quad g ↦ (0, …, 0, g, 0, … , 0).$$
Now $\prod_{i=1}^s \operatorname{Hom} (G_i,H) \cong \operatorname{Hom} (\bigoplus_{i=1}^s G_i,H)$, by
$$(φ_1, …, φ_s) ↦ φ_1 \oplus … \oplus φ_s\quad\text{and}\quad (ψ∘\mathrm{incl}_1, …, ψ∘\mathrm{incl}_s) ↤ ψ,$$
where $φ_1 \oplus … \oplus φ_s \colon G_1 \oplus … \oplus G_s → H,\; (g_1, …, g_s) ↦ φ_1(g_1) + … + φ_s(g_s)$.

This works for general products and direct sums as well.